# how to know how much time is left for a setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

basically what i am doing is set a timer to logout the user after a hour has passed but only if the user is inactive so i want to restart the timer after user has did any activity (scroll, keypress, mousemove, click) the thing is that the timer doesn't reset or something else thats why in the logout function i want to know did the timer actually reset and thats why i want to know the time passed by the timer.

i am using javascript, any help pls?

Comment: This isn't the way to to things. You should have the session time out on the server instead.

Comment: how will i reset the timer then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a "feature" -- sure use Javascript, but if security is your aim, use server side, no doubt about it.

It would be a big nuisance to have to code something to track every little change that could happen, scroll, click, focus, keypress, etc, to determine if the user was "idle" or not -- so it's an idea to use something like <s>**erichydns idleTimer**, jquery plugin: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/</s>

---

**edit:** this would be more suitable for you: http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/

demo is available here which shows in real time if the user is "idle" or not http://paulirish.com/demo/idle-timer

Comment: hi thanks for the comment, the plugin is good with only one problem it polls the server and i have to minimize the server requests is there a js alternative?

Comment: this one looks good let me check if this works thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can clar the setTimeout using the following code:

```
var t = setTimeout(myFunction,100000);
clearTimeout(t); //clear the timeout
```

If you want to know how much time is left, then you have to count the seconds or so ;)

Comment: i am doing exactly that

`code

function reset_interval()
{
 
if (timer != null)
{
//alert('f');
currTime = new Date();
clearTimeout(timer);
//clearInterval(timer);
timer = null;
//second step: implement the timer again<br />
timer = setTimeout(auto_logout,timeBeforeLogOut );
// completed the reset of the timer<br />
}
}`

Comment: Then your bug is somewhere else ;) clearTimeout is the way to do it. It works.